# Viewport rescaling lags when rotating portrait to landscape

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, viewport

When rotating the device from portrait to landscape, viewport rescaling lags thus creating a white background overflow.

The following device and browser were used. You can use yahoo site as sample.
Device : IPad Air
Browser: Safari
Website: www.yahoo.com

Below is my viewport config

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

What causes the lag in rescaling? Is this a hardware issue? Is the viewport scaling dependent on the processing speed of the device?

Comment: Each time a device or a viewport is changed, the rendering engine need to recalculate all aspects of the site. This action is very much dependant of the processing speed of the device you are using. If you do the same in Chrome Canary it goes almost instant, but you can still notice the changes.